# even though mvn clean install works fine from command prompt, build fails in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and maven.
I have maven project in eclipse. And I am using Jenkins for execution. 
When i execute the command "mvn clean install",  it works fine. But when I execute in Jenkins via Build now, it throws null pointer exception.

Please help me to solve this.

```
    pom.xml clean install
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Started by user praveen somayaji
Finished: ABORTED
FATAL: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
Caused: java.lang.Exception
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:179)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:179)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to Channel to Maven [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java, -cp
```

Comment: You forgot the log.

Comment: added log.. Please help me out.

Comment: Please add the full log output and not only excerpts. How have you called Maven? Which Maven Version? Which Jenkins Version ?

Comment: For me it worked after deleting Jenkins workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine now. I added command "mvn clean install" under Pre steps.
Maven Project-> Configure-> Pre Steps -> add above command -> Save.